# Entity Frame work issue - enable-migrations

Tags: .net, entity-framework

PM> enable-migrations

After Running above command I encounter the following issue but same command I run last night and it work well.

Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly
'file:///C:\Users\Raj\source\repos\ClothBazar\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

but here in image you can see the file available

[image]

At C:\Users\Raj\source\repos\ClothBazar\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:782 char:5

- ```
  $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-P ...
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

At C:\Users\Raj\source\repos\ClothBazar\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:783 char:5

- ```
  $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly
'file:///C:\Users\Raj\source\repos\ClothBazar\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

At C:\Users\Raj\source\repos\ClothBazar\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:811 char:5

- ```
  $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

Comment: 2 entityframework must balance.

Comment: check if you have two different versions of EF installed in the project? Go to Tool>Nuget PackageManager > Consolidate Tab > Select Entity Framework. Select the latest version and install it. This should fix it.